# how to pass angular array item into another function Image for Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fabricjs

I have an array in my controller like

```
$scope.image = [
{name: 'img1'},
{name: 'img2'},
{name: 'img3'},
{name: 'img4'},
{name: 'img5'},
...
]
```

I have it being displayed in html like

```
<a href=""><img ng-repeat="img in images" src="assets/img/{{ img.name }}" width="50"><span ng-click="anyImage()" ></span></a>
```

I have another function in my controller and i would like the be able to pass in the img.name value to that function,  so my question is how would i do that?

the other function looks like

```
$scope.anyImage = function(){
    fabric.Image.fromURL(image.name, function(oImg){
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `ng-click` from

```
ng-click="anyImage()"
```

to

```
ng-click="anyImage(img.name)"
```

and update the function binding to

```
$scope.anyImage = function(name){
```

Comment: And update the function to `$scope.anyImage = function(image.name){`

Comment: duh i see what i did scratch the last comment

Comment: Firstly, in ng attributes, you should not use `{{`.

Comment: For anybody else who needs a solution to this down the road   dont make silly mistakes     this answer helped but the main problem was i was not doing anything with the image  need to add `canvas.add(oImg);`  soo thank you nikhil for the answer!! and everybody else for your help as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `ng-repeat`in a `div` to contain the images and spans, in your way it repeats only the images but not the spans.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/ssgkuc1j/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div ng-repeat="img in images">
        <img  src="{{ img.name }}" width="50" />
        <span ng-click="anyImage(img.name)" >click</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.images = [{
        name: 'http://wallpaperswide.com/download/summer_scenery-wallpaper-800x600.jpg',
    }, {
        name: 'http://wallpaperswide.com/download/wheat_ears-wallpaper-800x600.jpg'
    } ];

    $scope.anyImage = function (image) {
        console.log(image);
    };
}]);
```

PS
I changed the names to display something, I added a `hello` text in the `span` to be clicked